# uploading coredata to cloudkit

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, cloudkit

I have a coredata project but I need to share my data and I want to use cloudkit to share it with the users of my app. My coredata project has 3 entities:

[image]

My question for you guys is how can I generate the relationship in cloudkit in the same way I have it in coredata

I'll really appreciate you help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a field of type CKReference which would be contain the recordID of a record of a different recordType. You do have to be aware that you can not perform queries over multiple recordTypes. Zo If you would like to search your content recordType for a specific tag or category, then also include it as text in the Content recordType

Comment: I'm really having trouble implementing CKReference to upload my  core data model to cloudKit. Do you have any examples of how can implement this?

Comment: Not one that's strait forward. If you have a look at https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao then you can see the Message.swift has a setter method for setting the reference. in the EVCloudKitDao it's written to CloudKit

Comment: Check out CKSIncrementalStore. It will handle relationships for you. https://github.com/CloudKitSpace/CKSIncrementalStore